# How to add a string to the front of every other column?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
Input_SNP_CHR Input_SNP_BP Set_1_CHR Set_1_BP Set_2_CHR  Set_2_BP Set_3_CHR Set_3_BP
            4    184648954        18 71883827         7 135798891         7 91206783
           13     34371442        14 52254555         1 223293324         7 54912662
           18     71883393        22 50428069         7 138698825         8 97486210
```

I would like to add the string "chr" to every CHR column to make my output look like:

```
Input_SNP_CHR Input_SNP_BP Set_1_CHR Set_1_BP Set_2_CHR  Set_2_BP Set_3_CHR Set_3_BP
         chr4    184648954     chr18 71883827      chr7 135798891      chr7 91206783
        chr13     34371442     chr14 52254555      chr1 223293324      chr7 54912662
        chr18     71883393     chr22 50428069      chr7 138698825      chr8 97486210
```

Comment: Use `paste` or `sprintf`?

Comment: try `df[,grep("CHR", names(df))] <- lapply(df[,grep("CHR", names(df))], function(x) paste0("chr", x))`

Comment: I tried this and it said there was an unexpected ']' in "data[,grep("CHR", names(data)]"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a combination of `grepl`, `sprintf`, and `lapply`:

```
CHR <- grepl("CHR", names(mydf))

mydf[CHR] <- lapply(mydf[CHR], sprintf, fmt = "chr%s")
mydf
#   Input_SNP_CHR Input_SNP_BP Set_1_CHR Set_1_BP Set_2_CHR  Set_2_BP Set_3_CHR Set_3_BP
# 1          chr4    184648954     chr18 71883827      chr7 135798891      chr7 91206783
# 2         chr13     34371442     chr14 52254555      chr1 223293324      chr7 54912662
# 3         chr18     71883393     chr22 50428069      chr7 138698825      chr8 97486210
```

Since your comment indicates that you are using `data.table`s and not `data.frame`s, you can try the following instead:

```
CHR <- grep("CHR", names(DT), value = TRUE)
DT[, (CHR) := lapply(.SD, sprintf, fmt = "chr%s"), .SDcols = CHR][]
```

Comment: I got this error: `"In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, CHR, value = structure(list( ... :
  NAs introduced by coercion"`

Comment: @Evan, well, it helps if you correctly identify that you are dealing with `data.table`s, and not `data.frame`s....

Comment: class(data) give me both  "data.table" and "data.frame", how should I proceed?

Comment: @Evan, see my update (sample dataset named "DT") for a "data.table" approach.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mutate_each` from `dplyr`, then `paste` the 'chr' with the columns that have 'CHR' as part of the column name.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
   mutate_each(funs(paste0('chr', .)), matches('CHR'))
#    Input_SNP_CHR Input_SNP_BP Set_1_CHR Set_1_BP Set_2_CHR  Set_2_BP Set_3_CHR
#1          chr4    184648954     chr18 71883827      chr7 135798891      chr7
#2         chr13     34371442     chr14 52254555      chr1 223293324      chr7
#3         chr18     71883393     chr22 50428069      chr7 138698825      chr8
#  Set_3_BP
#1 91206783
#2 54912662
#3 97486210
```